# Cannot create the Silverlight ASP.NET website in Visual Studio 2008 Web Developer edition

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

I need to create a ASp.net website with silverlight controls.

I am having only express editions of 2008 (Web developer edition and C# express editions).

I have created the WPF application sing C# expression and create the new XAML files.

Then I have created asp.net website in web developer edition and linked the xaml files with the .

But nothing works.

Note: I have not silverlight application project types and templates in Visual Studio 2008 web developer edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to install the Service pack 1

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Web Developer, and if you are not getting template to create silverlight, then probably you need to install Silverlight add on from this link

www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=c22d6a7b-546f-4407-8ef6-d60c8ee221ed&displaylang=en